# How to parse response from remote server use json? I use retrofit and bearer token

Tags: json, parsing, gson, retrofit2, interceptor

By okhttp log I know I get response from remote server. But when I try to parse response I receive null! How to correct parse response from the server to get data?

My Data object:

```
@Parcelize
data class DataItem(

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

) : Parcelable
```

MY Api:

```
interface Api {

    @GET("v1/media/list/image")
    suspend fun getImage(): DataItem
}
```

My Retrofit object:

```
  private val httpClient = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .protocols(listOf(Protocol.HTTP_1_1))
        .addInterceptor(BearerTokenInterceptor(TOKEN))
        .addInterceptor(logInterceptor())

    //get api by retrofit
    private val api: TVApi by lazy {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()
        retrofit.create(TVApi::class.java)
    }

    private fun logInterceptor() : HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

        return interceptor
    }
```

My try to parse the response:

```
 private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    private fun getNetworkResponse() {

        scope.launch {
            try {
                Log.d(MY_TAG, "api: ${api.getVideo()}")

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.e(MY_TAG, "IOException: $e")
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Log.e(MY_TAG, "HttpException: $e")
            }
        }
    }
```

OKhttp log:

```
{"code":200,"message":"Success","data":[{"name"....}
```

My Log:

```
api: DataItem(extension=null, size=null, name=null, url=null)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data class does not match the JSON structure. Gson does not report missing or unknown properties, which is why this mismatch might not be obvious.

Your JSON data suggests there should be an enclosing data class, let's call it `Response`:

```kotlin
data class Response(
    val code: Int,
    val message: String,
    val data: List<DataItem>,
)
```

And then the function in your `Api` interface should have that as return type:

```kotlin
interface Api {

    @GET("v1/media/list/image")
    suspend fun getImage(): Response
}
```

(Also, please check the code in your question again. The `Api` interface has a function called `getImage`, but in your code below you call `getVideo`; and your log output shows that `DataItem` has additional properties such as `extension`, which are not shown in the code of your `DataItem` class above.)

Answer (score 0):

By mistake I called DataItem object instead VideoResponse or ImageResponse

My JSON:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Welcome",
            "url": "https://...",
            "size": "27.34MB",
            "extension": "mp4"
        }
    ]
}
```

It parse to follow data classes:

```
@Parcelize
data class DataItem(

    @field:SerializedName("extension")
    val extension: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("size")
    val size: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("name")
    val name: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("url")
    val url: String? = null
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class ImageResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<DataItem?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null
) : Parcelable

@Parcelize
data class VideoResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("code")
    val code: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<DataItem?>? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null
) : Parcelable
```